# Height Map xyz coordinates

Tags: ros-indigo, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using velodyne height map , so far i am struggling to only view the x,y,z coordinates of obstacles. even once I try to edit on  heightmap.cpp file nothing changing in output. what could be best way to as to only view the coordinates without the raw data matrix.
if anyone can clarify to me what is meant by offset
for instance
this means that the value of the x is on zero position  in the raw data matrix.

```
  seq: 22
  stamp: 
    secs: 1518471618
    nsecs: 669806000
  frame_id: velodyne
height: 1
width: 480
fields: 
  - 
    name: x
    offset: 0
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: y
    offset: 4
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: z
    offset: 8
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
  - 
    name: intensity
    offset: 16
    datatype: 7
    count: 1
is_bigendian: False
point_step: 32
row_step: 15360
```

thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284362/height-map-xyz-coordinates/) by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-03-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-05**:
What topic is the output you posted from?

**Comment by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on 2018-03-05**:
velodyne_obstacles topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [PointCloud Library](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) to unpack the data from those messages.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on 2018-03-05**:
yea, that's what I am trying to do.I am new using ROS. so even when I try to update the .cpp file nothing changes in the output. or is there such a way to unpack the point cloud using terminal commands.
thank you

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-03-05**:
That link tells you how to do that in C++ code. There are also many tutorials.

**Comment by [Karim Ahmt](https://answers.ros.org/users/33767/karim-ahmt/) on 2018-03-06**:
well, i recorded that a bag from VLP-16, which don't record RGB data. will the libraries still work.thank you

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-03-06**:
Yes, it just needs x, y, z